# text align center html/css

Tags: html, css

[the problem pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6EzL.png)

ok i want the [buy] text to be in center the problem that i write text-align: center;
but nothing worked
and thats the code..

```css
.buy {
    background-color: rgb(73, 73, 247);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;

}
.f {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.pros {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 42px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}

.mac {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.new {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: orangered;
    margin-bottom: 0;

}
.p {
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<p class="new">
    New
</p>
<p class="mac">
    MacBook Pro
</p>
<p class="pros">
    Supercharged for pros.
</p>
<p class="f">
   From $1999 
</p>
<p>
   <span class="buy">Buy</span>
</p>
```

Comment: _"some details because the website is saying my post is mostly code"_ - did it say add details, or random gibberish? -1 for this dumb attempt to "cheat the system."

Comment: Typo?  Your CSS is targeting a `.p` class, but your HTML *has no* `p` class.  Did you mean to target the `<p>` *elements*?  `p { /* css rules */ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last p need class and you should write text-align:center for your p not span i show you how to write this code in html and css:

```
   <p class="buy1">
   <span class="buy">Buy</span>
   </p>


    .buy1{
    text-align: center;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its span span is an inline element if u want to centre cover it with div.

Comment: what do you mean by cover it with div sorry im still learning

Comment: @Mohamad i just mean like this ```<div><span></span></div> ```
give class to parent div of span and there u can center it buy text-align:center

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buy {
    background-color: rgb(73, 73, 247);
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 30px;

}
.f {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.pros {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 42px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}

.mac {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.new {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: orangered;
    margin-bottom: 0;

}
.p{
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <p class="new">
      New
  </p>
  <p class="mac">
      MacBook Pro
  </p>
  <p class="pros">
      Supercharged for pros.
  </p>
  <p class="f">
     From $1999 
  </p>
  <p>
     <span class="buy">Buy</span>
  </p>
</div>
```